# i have two table and i have problem to group by name and show all data transaction with header in mysql

Tags: mysql

1. tblcustomer

| id | datecreated | custname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-01 | tom |
| 2 | 2022-12-01 | john |
| 3 | 2022-12-02 | john |
| 4 | 2022-12-01 | carles |
| 5 | 2022-12-01 | diki |

2. tbltransaction

| id | custID | name | qty | kodemat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abc | 10 | 2201 |
| 2 | 1 | ab | 10 | 2201 |
| 3 | 1 | aa | 10 | 2202 |
| 4 | 2 | ab | 5 | 2202 |
| 5 | 2 | ac | 5 | 2203 |
| 6 | 1 | ac | 20 | 2204 |

expected result, group by name and create header tbl kodemat 1 - 3 and sum qty

| datereated | name | kodemat 1 | kodemat 2 | kodemat 3 | sumqty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | abc | 2201 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 2022-12-01 | ab | 2201 | 2202 | 0 | 15 |
| 2022-12-01 | aa | 2202 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 2022-12-01 | ac | 2203 | 2204 | 0 | 25 |

my query and result

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,group_concat(a.kodemat order by a.id limit 5 ) kodemat, sum(a.qty) qty, datecreated,custname 
from tbltransaction a join tblcustomer b on b.id = a.custID 
where a.qty >'0' group by a.name;
```

| datereated | name | kodemat | sum qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | abc | 2201 0 0 | 10 |
| 2022-12-01 | ab | 2201 ,2202 , 0 | 15 |
| 2022-12-01 | aa | 2202 ,0 , 0 | 10 |
| 2022-12-01 | ac | 2203 ,2204 , 0 | 25 |

please help to create header tbl in mysql, thanks

Comment: I have not idea how you get from your start point to your desired endpoint. In particular datecreated seems to have nothing to do with part and there is no discernible way of deciding what kodemat goes into what kodemat columns 1-3 and why is sumqty for ab 15 when there are 25 in transactions.

Comment: You expect to have 3 kodemat everytime ?

Comment: thanks for your response, please ignore the datecreated column 
for ab 15 and 25 qty from the sum of qty columns in the transaction table based on the same name, sir.

Comment: yes , i expect 3 kodemat everytime

Answer (score 1):

We can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to split kodemat into columns as follows :

```
select datecreated, partname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(kodemat, ',', 1) AS 'kodemat1',
  CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(',', kodemat, 1) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(kodemat, ',', 2), ',', -1)
    END AS 'kodemat2',
  CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(',', kodemat, (LOCATE(',', kodemat, 1) + 1)) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(kodemat, ',', -1)
  END AS 'kodemat3',
  qty as 'sum qty'
from (
    SELECT b.datecreated, a.partname, group_concat(a.kodemat) as kodemat, sum(a.qty) as qty
    from tbltransaction a
    inner join tblcustomer b on b.id = a.custID 
    group by a.partname, b.datecreated
) as s;
```

check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/Ii6KmAmJ